# Split a .CSV by headings in the csv then into lists of strings

Tags: python, csv

I am coding in Python (I'm quite new to Python) and want to split a .csv file that looks like the example below. I would like each list of items containing line of csv which I then know how to split, using:

values = line.split(',')

fold 1

```
0.058824,0.529032,0.367347,0.23913,0.169471,0.243354,0.115713,0.433333,yes
0.529412,0.812903,0.510204,0.26087,0.169471,0.527607,0.13877,0.366667,yes
```

fold 2

```
0.176471,0.806452,0.510204,0.130435,0.133413,0.239264,0.081127,0.166667,yes
0.411765,0.632258,0.673469,0.184783,0.560096,0.249489,0.021349,0.366667,yes
```

fold 3

```
0.647059,0.606452,0.510204,0.206522,0.15625,0.366053,0.204526,0.483333,yes
0.411765,0.8,0.653061,0.380435,0.36899,0.408998,0.302733,0.316667,yes
```

Ideally we would want:

```
list[0] = ["0.058824,0.529032,0.367347,0.23913,0.169471,0.243354,0.115713,0.433333,yes" , "0.529412,0.812903,0.510204,0.26087,0.169471,0.527607,0.13877,0.366667,yes"] 
list[1] = ["0.176471,0.806452,0.510204,0.130435,0.133413,0.239264,0.081127,0.166667,yes" , "0.411765,0.632258,0.673469,0.184783,0.560096,0.249489,0.021349,0.366667,yes"]
```

and so on.
Thank you very much for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Your update makes my original answer no sense at all and I'm totally confused by your question now. To split a .csv file into different files in different folder, or to read .csv files from different folder in a list of list? Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
value = (line.split(' '))[-1].split(",")
```

split by space first and then pick up last element and then split by "," again.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
with open (filename,'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    if data != '':
        list1.append(data[7:])
```

## list1 will contain the list as you have mentioned